# Java web Application Error

Tags: java

So is was trying to make a application to search hotels and i came across some problems : my array wont show whilst there were no errors  and now its totally broken. Can someone see what i did wrong ?

```
package fact.it.www.dataaccess;

import fact.it.www.beans.Hotel;
import fact.it.www.beans.Skigebied;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DAHotel {

private Connection connection = null;

public DAHotel(String url, String login, String password, String driver) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Class.forName(driver);
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, password);
}

public void close() throws SQLException {
    if (connection != null) {
        connection.close();
    }
}


public ArrayList<Hotel> getOverzichtHotels() {
ArrayList<Hotel> overzichtHotels = new ArrayList<>();
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    try {
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM hotel order by hotelnaam");
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            Hotel hotel = new Hotel();
            hotel.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
            hotel.setHotelnaam(resultSet.getString("hotelnaam"));
            hotel.setSkigebied_id(resultSet.getInt("skigebied_id"));
            hotel.setAantalsterren(resultSet.getInt("aantalsterren"));
            hotel.setLigging(resultSet.getString("ligging"));
            hotel.setAccomodatie(resultSet.getString("accomodatie"));
            hotel.setKamers(resultSet.getInt("kamers"));
            hotel.setMaaltijden(resultSet.getString("maaltijden"));
            hotel.setPistes(resultSet.getString("pistes"));
            hotel.setfoto(resultSet.getString("foto"));
            overzichtHotels.add(hotel);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            statement.close();
            if (resultSet != null) {
                resultSet.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
    }
    return overzichtHotels;
}

}
```

Method used to call the array (in ManageServlet.java):

```
 if (request.getParameter("overzichtHotelsKnop") != null) {
        ArrayList<Hotel> overzichtHotels = dahotel.getOverzichtHotels();
        request.setAttribute("overzichtHotels", overzichtHotels);
        rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("overzichtHotels.jsp");
```

And the code used on index.jsp to go to the jsp :

And finally the code on overzichtHotels.jsp

```
<body>
    <%Hotel hotel = (Hotel) request.getAttribute("hotel");%>
    <div id="headercontainer">
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Hotel</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <h1><%=hotel.getHotelnaam() %></h1>                   
        <p> Het hotel: "<%=hotel.getHotelnaam()%>" </p>
        <p> Aantal sterren: <%=hotel.getAantalsterren()%> </p>

        <p>  <a href="index.jsp">Terug naar beginpagina</a></p>
    </div>
</body>
```

and here is a link to the whole project + a youtube clip of what we have to do :
  [project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4LJ3SIo8uHMV3M4VWxwT2ZvNzQ/view?usp=sharing)

[Youtube link to final project](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLA-7BYbcek)

Comment: Which array? The one resulting from the execution of `getOverzichtHotels()` ?

Comment: please provide a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This is a good time to spend a few hours learning how to use a debugger.

Comment: how are you trying to call or render the arraylist?

Comment: @OldProgrammer my professor didn't teach us how to use the debugger ;(, and they provided us with only 1 example throughout the semester

Comment: oh ok @Aaron will do

Comment: @Aaron shortened the code in my question and provided extra information

Comment: In the Servlet you set a `overzichtHotels` List, yet in the JSP you try to retrieve a single `hotel`, from an attribute which is probably undefined. You could try displaying the data from the `overzichtHotels` attribute directly, but it will probably just display an ArrayList instance id. At this point you'll at least know you're correctly retrieving the data in your JSP, and you'll just have to loop over it and display the individual `hotel`s instead of directly displaying the list.